# I'm stuck with while loop on my random number guessing game

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

Want it to loop through everything until the user puts in the right number. When the user puts in wrong number it should say "type in a different number". When the user puts in the right number it should say "congrats you won". But until then it will loop and say "type in a different number" and after 5 tries I want it to say "you failed this mission! do you want to try again?"

If they guess it on 1 try they will be giving 500 dollar and second try 400 dollar and so on until 5 tries.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Projekt_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WELCOME TO GUESS GAME!" + "\nYou gonna guess a number between 1 and 20 " + "\nYou have  5 tries to guess the number! " + "\nYou gonna get more money on less tries, highest win are 500 dollar on one try! " + "\nHOPE YOU LIKE IT :)");

        Random talet = new Random();
        int secretnumber = talet.nextInt(20) + 1;
        int tries = 0;
        int money = 600;
        String number;

        int guess;
        boolean win = false;

        while (win == false) {
            number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 20");
            guess = Integer.parseInt(number);
            tries++;

            if (guess == secretnumber) {
                win = true;
            } else if (guess > secretnumber) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your number is to low :(" + "\nType in a higher number!");
                guess = Integer.parseInt(number);
            } else if (guess < secretnumber) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your number is to high :(" + "\nType ina a lower number!");
                guess= Integer.parseInt(number);
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats you won!" + "\nYour number was " + secretnumber + "\nit took you " + tries + "tries");
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume `försök` counts the number of tries? If so, you're gonna wanna add a second condition to your loop that terminates it if `försök` equals `4`.

Comment: Please translate the code. Questions and code should be in English http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange.

Comment: Edited to english now :)

Comment: For this kind of issue, I strongly suggest you learn how to use a debugger and go through your code line-by-line. The problem would be obvious.

Comment: see the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an additional condition in `while` loop will work. If `försök` is the number of tries which can have maxium value of `5` (in your case) then condition should be :

```
while (win == false && försök<5) //if försök starts from 0 
{
   //code
   if(win==true)
   break;
   försök++;
}
```

To display the message and score you can just check the value of `försök` after `while` loop:

```
if(försök==5)
{
      // display this message: "you failed this mission! do you want to try again?" 
     score=0;
}
else
{
     //display: "congrats you won"
      score=(5-försök)*100;
}
```

Basically your code should be like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

class Projekt_1
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int maxTries = 5;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome... " + maxTries + " tries ... 500 krones ");

        final Random rnd = new Random();
        final int hemligtnummer = rnd.nextInt(20) + 1;
        int tryCounter = 0;
        final int pengar = 500;
        String nummer;

        int guess = -1;

        while (guess != hemligtnummer && tryCounter < maxTries) {
            if(tryCounter==0)
            nummer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("...a number 1 and 20");
            else
            nummer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter no...");
            guess = Integer.parseInt(nummer);
            if (guess == hemligtnummer) {
                break;
            } else if (guess > hemligtnummer) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try " + (tryCounter+1) + " was too big try a smaller one");
            } else if (guess < hemligtnummer) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try " + (tryCounter+1) + " too small try a bigger one");
            }
            tryCounter++;
        }
        if(tryCounter==5){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Grattis du vann!" + "\nteh number was " + hemligtnummer + "\nDet tog dig " + tryCounter + " försök");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your price is :" + (pengar - tryCounter * 100) + " Krones");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"congrats you won"+"Your price is :" + (pengar - tryCounter * 100) + " Krones" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will add that, you man first that while loop than the other one if (försök == 5) under that?

Comment: Thank you! Gonna try it out, but do the program give you 500/400/300/200/100 dollar when you have 1/2/3/4/5 tries? if you know what I mean

Comment: This program will say "put in a higher number" and go back to "put in a number between 1 and 20" everytime, not execute "you win" if you put in the right number and if you put in the wrong number it will not say "put in a lower number" certain times

Comment: I updated the code ,and it is running fine!.@Lucke GG

Comment: Thank you so much man, you made my 2 days long pain great again! :D

Comment: So now the program works perfect! But under: if(tryCounter==5){ I want it to say "Do you want to play again YES/NO?" and then have a code that do the program all over again when they type in "YES"

Comment: You have to think this of your own... put the whole code in a do-while loop and check for user's input YES /NO to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a control break while loop. which will be broken when the number of attempts become more then 5 OR when the correct number is inputted.
See the below for reference

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfTries = 0;
        int input;
        int correctNumn = 15;

        while (true) {

            input = s.nextInt();
            if (input != correctNumn && numOfTries <= 5) {

                numOfTries++;
                if (numOfTries == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Game Over");
                    break;
                }

                continue;
            } else if (input == correctNumn) {
                System.out.println("corect ans");
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: how do I do it with swing? you are using util now

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to help you if you post all in your native language... but here is my answer...

the issue with your code was in the hole logi, you never use the variable tries(försök) and If the user guess a wrong number then you read the try again but instead you should start the logic of the while again....

anyways....

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int maxTries = 5;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome... " + maxTries + " tries ... 500 krones ");

        final Random rnd = new Random();
        final int hemligtnummer = rnd.nextInt(20) + 1;
        int tryCounter = 0;
        final int pengar = 600;
        String nummer;

        int guess = -1;

        while (guess != hemligtnummer && tryCounter < maxTries) {
            nummer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("...a number 1 and 20");
            guess = Integer.parseInt(nummer);
            tryCounter++;

            if (guess == hemligtnummer) {
                break;
            } else if (guess > hemligtnummer) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try " + tryCounter + " was too big try a smaller one");
            } else if (guess < hemligtnummer) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try " + tryCounter + "too small try a bigger one");
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Grattis du vann!" + "\nteh number was " + hemligtnummer + "\nDet tog dig " + tryCounter + " försök");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your price is :" + (pengar - tryCounter * 100) + " Krones");
    }
```